# Dock a div to left of window and clicking again to original position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a web page that has three section i.e. `Header , Mid, Footer.`
In Mid div it is again divided into two parts i.e. leftdiv and rightdiv. Leftdiv has vertical menu and right div is for content holder for the respective page.

Now i want to dock leftdiv to left of the window screen on button click and when user again click of the same button the leftdiv should set as original position.

ex: if left and right `div` area has `respectively 30 : 70 % area of main div`. when i click on button the left and right div area should like `10:90 %` and clicking again both div gets their original ratio.

```
var checker = new Boolean();
checker = true;
if (checker = true) {

    $("#Test").click(function() {

        $('.left-wrap').animate({
            left: "10%"
        }, 400);
        checker = false;
    });
}
if (checker != true) {
    $("#Test").click(function() {
        $('.left-wrap').animate({
            left: "30%"
        }, 400);
        checker = true;
    });
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: And what did you tried so far?

Comment: I have update my question again.

Comment: why downvote to thsi question ?? I urge to the downvoters here please comment the reasons too . Otherwise the newbie will never take initiatives due to downvote fear . Your reasons will enhance their performance of presenting their questions right .

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged jquery in your question:

**HTML code**

```
<div class="toggle left">
    Menu
</div>

<div class="toggle right">
    Page contents
</div>

<button id="switch">Big monster!</button>
```

**CSS code**

```
div.toggle {
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.left {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #f00;
}

div.right {
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #0f0;
}

div.left.switch {
    width: 10%;
}

div.right.switch {
    width: 90%;
}
```

**Javascript code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#switch').on('click', function () {
        $('div.toggle').toggleClass('switch');
    });
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/9xr46zqt/

---

### EDIT

To animate, use CSS `transition` property on the divs:

```
div.toggle {
    transition: width 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
```

See updated fiddle with animation: http://jsfiddle.net/9xr46zqt/1/

If course, you can specify *anything* in both the `.switch` and non-switched classes. If you want to animate those as well, list their properties in the `transition`, like: `transition: width, left, color 0.25s ease-in-out`, or use `transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out`.